# How can I download and save a file using JavaScript (no browser)

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm using node.js to run some JavaScript using "node test.js" and want to result in saving a file from the given URL, but whenever I search for downloading files (as expected) i just find info on how to trigger a browser download. S i'm struggling to work out how to do it. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Glen x

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');

fetch("https://lex-audio.useremarkable.com/mp3/viscera_gb_1.mp3").then(res => res.text()).then(
    txt => {
        fs.writeFile('src/assets/audio.mp3', txt, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        } );
    }

);
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code you included in your question?

Comment: I just get a file that doesn't play anything, and have no clue why.

Comment: @Link19 does the file contain data or is it empty? The problem could be the data written to the file.

Comment: It's not empty, but i can't read an mp3 file. Though when i compare it to the download it does look very similar but the very start of the file looks different. Unfortunately i have no clue about audio file encoding, I wasn't even sure it that was the right way to download a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node-fetch will certainly work for downloading an http resource such as an MP3 file.

But, MP3 data is not UTF-8 text, so you need to treat the download as binary. Replace `res.text()` with `res.buffer()`.  This change works for me and I'm able to play the downloaded audio file:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');

const url = "https://lex-audio.useremarkable.com/mp3/viscera_gb_1.mp3";

fetch(url).then(res => res.buffer()).then(buffer => {
    return fs.promises.writeFile('audio.mp3', buffer);
}).then(() => {
    console.log("done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Note, since we're already using promises with `fetch()`, I used the promise version of `writeFile` since error handling and success tracking of the two integrates much more cleanly this way.

Comment: `res.buffer` is no exist in type `Response` that fetch returns.

Comment: @tannerman - This exact code still works for me in nodejs v16.14.2.  Are you running this in nodejs?  Using the browser version of fetch in a browser, it has `res.arrayBuffer()` and `res.blob()`.

Comment: thanks. I miss "node-fetch" prefer to native node "fetch". It works